# Could not load library cudart64_110.dll with tensor flow gpu installation

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
After this, there comes a traceback error which says on the last line: "from tensorflow.summary import FileWriter
ImportError: cannot import name 'FileWriter' from 'tensorflow.summary' (C:\Users\HP\tetris-ai\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\summary_tf\summary_*init*_.py)

After installing tensoflow gpu again, I got this error
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
tensorflow 2.6.2 requires keras<2.7,>=2.6.0, but you have keras 2.7.0 which is incompatible.
tensorflow 2.6.2 requires tensorflow-estimator<2.7,>=2.6.0, but you have tensorflow-estimator 2.7.0 which is incompatible.
Successfully installed keras-2.7.0 tensorflow-estimator-2.7.0 tensorflow-gpu-2.7.0

But my issue with the dll and traceback error continued.In Vscode and in pycharm.

Comment: Please format you post with the option available like the `code` tag, so it's easier for all to read and then try to all you.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you need a Nvidia GPU, CUDA is the language NVIDIA uses.

You can check if you have one following these steps: Windows -> Task Manager.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).